# Rust: How to define a common behaviour for some "subclasses" of a trait?

Tags: inheritance, rust, abstract-class, traits

There is this pattern where some functionality of an abstract class is provided by its abstract subclass, like this (TypeScript):

```
abstract class Foo{  // could also be an interface
    abstract foo(): number;
}

abstract class FooFromBar{
    foo() { return this.bar() + 1; }
    abstract bar(): number;
}

class Data1 extends FooFromBar{
    bar() { return 5; }
}

alert(new Data1().foo());  // 6
```

Now I can have more classes extending `FooFromBar` that use the `foo=bar+1` functionality, plus more classes extending `Foo` directly providing custom `foo`.

Now I want the same in Rust. My intuition is that the abstract classes become traits, and concrete classes become e.g. structs implementing them - but that might be wrong, I'm quite new to Rust. And the problem is I don't know how to get `foo` implemented automatically for types implementing `FooFromBar`. The best I got is this:

```
trait Foo{
    fn foo(&self)->i32;
}

trait FooFromBar:Foo{
    fn bar(&self)->i32;
}
impl<S:FooFromBar> Foo for S{
    fn foo(&self)->i32{self.bar()+1}
}

struct DataBar;
impl FooFromBar for DataBar{
    fn bar(&self)->i32{5}
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}",DataBar.foo());  // 6
}
```

It works, but there's a serious problem with this approach. If I add another "sub-trait", e.g. `FooFromBaz` implementing `foo=baz+2` like this:

```
trait FooFromBaz:Foo{
    fn baz(&self)->i32;
}
impl<S:FooFromBaz> Foo for S{
    fn foo(&self)->i32{self.baz()+2}
}
```

then I get an error that there are conflicting implementations:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `Foo`:
  --> src/main.rs:19:1
   |
8  | impl<S:FooFromBar> Foo for S{
   | ---------------------------- first implementation here
...
19 | impl<S:FooFromBaz> Foo for S{
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation
```

It looks to me that they are only conflicting if someone actually creates a type that implements both `FooFromBar` and `FooFromBaz` - that would really mean they did an unreasonable thing. But instead it fails even without any structs implementing any of them.

So the question is how to obtain a similar behaviour correctly? Is there some better generics magic to obtain that, or is it just something that should be solved completely differently in Rust and the problem is just that I'm stuck with thinking about classes?

Comment: If you're willing to use nightly, specialization should be helpful. https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844